# How nopcommerce plug-in is loaded view?

Tags: plugins, nopcommerce, viewengine

How is the nopcommerce plug-in loaded in the view?

The ThemeableRazorViewEngine view rewrite engine found no relevant information and Plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a version:

1. Plugin controllers in version 3.50 (and above) explicitly retunt a plugin view (copied to a plugin output directory).
2. In previous versions plugins views were embedded in plugin DLLs. And nopCommerce used embedded view engine

Comment: why did you change from embedding to explicitly copying the content? did you see any disadvantage on this?